# Triggers on TextBox in DataGrid's DataTemplate are not Working

Tags: c#-4.0, mvvm, .net-4.0, silverlight-4.0

While working on `MVVM in Silverlight 4.0`. I got stuck with following problem.
See the following `Xaml`. And note that in TextBox1 the Method `UpdateText` (under interaction triggers) is working but in `TextBox2` which is the part of `DataGrid's` Template,Here method '`UpdateText`' is not working at all. Can anyone help me out to call a method on `TextChanged` Event of `TextBox2`?
(UpdateText is just a simple method in `MVVM` class working with `TextBox1` but not with TextBox2)

Here is the xaml :

```
<UserControl xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"  x:Class="MVVMEventTriggerDemo.Views.MainView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MVVMEventTriggerDemo.ViewModels"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:si="clr-namespace:Expression.Samples.Interactivity;assembly=Expression.Samples.Interactivity"
Height="600" Width="700">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <viewModel:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewmodel"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewmodel}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="258*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="262*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="textbox1" Text="{Binding EmployeeName, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="142,77,20,289" Grid.Column="1">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                <si:CallDataMethod Method="UpdateText"/>
                <si:ShowMessageBox Caption="Thank you"
                                   Message="Thanks for trying the Example"
                                   MessageBoxButton="OK"/>
                <si:SetProperty TargetName="textbox1" PropertyName="Background" Value="PaleGoldenrod"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
    <Button Content="Show Message" Width="100" Height="25" Margin="142,113,20,258" Grid.Column="1">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <si:CallDataMethod Method="HandleShowMessage"/>
                <si:ShowMessageBox Caption="Thank you"
                                   Message="Thanks for trying the Example"
                                   MessageBoxButton="OK"/>
                <si:SetProperty TargetName="LayoutRoot" PropertyName="Background" Value="PaleGoldenrod"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
    <sdk:DataGrid 
        x:Name="dgDevice" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        Margin="13,13,13,13"
        BorderThickness="1,0,1,1"
        RowBackground="White"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="320" 
        Opacity="0.9"
        Background="White"
        GridLinesVisibility="None"
        HeadersVisibility="None"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ActualColors,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="320" >
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Width="auto">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"  />                                   
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

           <TextBox x:Name="textbox2" Text="{Binding EmployeeName, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="100" Height="30" Margin="142,77,20,289" Grid.Column="1">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
              <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                <si:CallDataMethod Method="UpdateText"/>
                <si:ShowMessageBox Caption="Thank you"
                                   Message="Thanks for trying the Example"
                                   MessageBoxButton="OK"/>
                <si:SetProperty TargetName="textbox2" PropertyName="Background" Value="PaleGoldenrod"/>
                 </i:EventTrigger>
               </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBox>
       </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

i not sure it can help you but in Datatemplate binding will goes like

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.BusyText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

i think you may have to bind event same as text bind in upper sentence.

Comment: I tried what you have suggested but it doesn't help/solve the issue in the context of the asked question. Please update the answer with more relevant info if possible.

Comment: @SaurabhRai: you have parent control UserControl?can you please post question with your code so I can suggest well